# DBpedia: How to extract all organization in specific country and specific language

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am new to DBpedia and I want to extract all organizations in specific country (ex France) and specific language (ex fr). I am using snorkel and have this query:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT ?org {
  SELECT DISTINCT ?org {
    ?org a/rdfs:subClassOf* dbo:Organisation .
 } ORDER BY ?org
}
```

What should I do next? I checked several tutorials but still have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Step 0 is to remove the sub-select.  The only time sub-selects are really needed is when aggregates are being computed and used to find other triples.

Step 1 then is to begin exploring how DBPedia represents countries and language.  Try the following query:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT *
WHERE {
   ?org a/rdfs:subClassOf* dbo:Organisation .
   ?org ?p ?o
} ORDER BY ?org
```

From there you'll find that `dbo:location` is used to represent the location of an organization.  Then replace the `?p` with `dbo:location` and do the same kind of exploration on the country to get the language.

In those explorations, you may find that different properties are used to represent country, etc.  DBPedia isn't always consistent and therefore exploring with SPARQL is a very useful way of understanding how to query the data.

Comment: I follow your step replace the sixth line with following:  but I got an error.
`?org duo:location:France`
I know it might be a basic syntactic error.I already check [this tutorial] (http://www.cambridgesemantics.com/semantic-university/sparql-by-example but still don't know how to write sparql correctly. or do you suggest any tutorial?

Comment: I think you need `?org duo:location :France`.  Note the space after `duo:location`.  For SPARQL education, Google `SPARQL tutorial`.  SPARQL by Example is pretty good.